# Julia import large out-of-memory csv data

Tags: julia

I was wondering if Julia has a package similar to Sparklyr in R that could handle out of memory data. My data is 11 GB in csv format.

I installed HPAT package in Julia, but I am not sure if it helps to handle big data. In addition, I noticed that there is a Spark package in Julia, does it have any function that enables me to import local data, like the spark_read_csv function in Sparklyr?

Comment: Julia has very good cross-language interfaces, look up PyCall, RCall, JavaCall for their obvious uses. Also, reading only a slice of the data and getting it into more compact format than CSV could save development/research time.

Comment: @DanGetz Is there any Julia package that works like sparklyr? I mean, that could enable me to use Spark or similar big data tools?

Comment: The question is too vague. It would be much better to explain what kind of processing/algorithm you want to apply, to what kind of data. If you are interested in Spark, then ask about Spark with a detailed example. There is a package called [Spark.jl](https://github.com/dfdx/Spark.jl). Perhaps you can check it (I have no experience with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaDB.jl. This package is pretty new and still in development, but it is capable of loading CSV datasets larger than memory.